How do I properly implement the python-can library's BLFWriter and Notifier for real-time tasks?
I am working on a tool that utilizes CAN buses to send and receive messages to and from a controller that I need to constantly monitor. A previous implementation of the code uses a loop to directly read from the CAN bus and immediately logs that message to a *.blf file using the BLFWriter in the python-can library, then it will analyze that message and store it in a dictionary of messages that I can always grab the most recently transmitted value from. I am trying to implement the Notifier class to constantly listen to the CAN bus and send the data where it needs to go by adding listeners, the only issue with this is that the *.blf recordings should be in real time and the processing of the message takes up to a second or so. I need these processes to happen simultaneously and do not know the best way to go about it. Is this something that I should be looking to use the threading library in Python for? I know that I need to be concerned about having too many threads running at the same time as they can become very resource intensive (and this would be as though there was roughly 100 threads running at the same just for the message decoding). If I shouldn't be using the threading library, is there another library best suited for this such as the multiprocessing library? Still somewhat new to Python and I don't know best practices for implementing certain functionalities.
I have tried a simple implementation below that uses the threading module to simulate analyzing the messages as well as logging them, but with a CAN message period of 10ms there are quite a few threads that open/close simultaneously (roughly 100 open at the same time).
from can import Notifier, BLFWriter
from can.interfaces.pcan import PcanBus
from can.interfaces.vector import VectorBus
import time
import threading

def run_decode(msg):
    test = threading.Thread(target=decode_message,args=[msg])
    test.isDaemon = True
    test.start()

def decode_message(msg):
    # Simulate the time it takes to decode a message
    print(msg)
    time.sleep(1)

def main():
    file = "testing.blf"

    logger = BLFWriter(file=file)

    can_bus = PcanBus(interface="pcan", channel="PCAN_USBBUS1", bitrate=500000, device_id=0xFF, receive_own_messages=True) # PCAN BUS
    # can_bus = VectorBus(interface="vector", channel=0, bitrate=500000, serial=96869, receive_own_messages=True) # VECTOR BUS

    notifier = Notifier(can_bus, [logger.on_message_received, run_decode])

    try:
        print("I am in the loop.")
        time.sleep(10)  # Run for 10 seconds for example
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
    finally:
        # Cleanup
        notifier.stop()  # Stop the Notifier
        can_bus.shutdown()  # Close the CAN bus
        logger.stop()  # Stop the BLFWrite

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

I am wondering how I can do this by just running the decode_message function instead of having to thread it to get the desired result. I was hoping that asyncio would be able to help me, but after a failed implementation (that could just be my own shortcomings when it comes to using asyncio) I was not able to achieve my desired outcome. Is there a best practice for implementing something like this with an operation being called roughly every 10ms that could take up to 1 full second without preventing the mainloop (the code in question is a customtkinter GIU application, but I don't personally think the GUI code to be relevant to this problem other than it needing to be responsive) from running? I can provide any further clarification if needed/requested.

Look for concurrent.futures instead of  threading.
This will allow you to even use subprocesses instead of threads, so that your processing and responses to the network can run in independent CPU cores.

@jsbueno thank you for your comment! I haven't really used this library before so I'm kind of unsure as to how to properly use it:
What is the max allowable number of workers that I can use? I would think I would need at least 100 (or potentially more in this case) to be able to keep up with the amount of messages I would be processing at the same time.
I'm still fairly new to Python as a whole and am still trying to digest all of the available libraries that are available to use.
